# IText PDF Library : Embedded video, how to show thumbnail and playback controls

Tags: itext

When I open the PDF document generated using the iText example to embed video in a PDF document, [IText Example Code](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=188), the document appears blank.

1. Is there a way to show a video thumbnail when the video is not playing, so reader of the document will have some clue that there is a video in it
2. Is there a way to insert Play, Pause, Stop buttons etc to control playback
3. The video does not plan in all environments, I had success only on my windows laptop with Acrobat reader. With Mac and Linux the video does not play. Also when PDF is opened inside a browser the video does not play. Is it a limitation or I am missing something ?
4. When I open the generated PDF and scroll down to the page with video I get a warning - "Features disabled to avoid security risks" - Is there a way embed video in a different way to avoid seeing this  message ?

Comment: That is an old example, based on ISO-32000-1. The technology used for that example will be deprecated in ISO-32000-2 (due for publication in 2016). If you want your application to be future-proof, it would be better to use a RichMedia annotation instead of a Screen annotation. Note that the movie plays when I open the PDF in Adobe Reader *after* I indicate that I accept the security risks. *Before* I do so and *before* I click the annotation, the document indeed shows a blank page. By the way: it is possible to create a RichMedia annotation using iText, but I don't have such an example yet.

Comment: Thanks Bruno Lowagie. I reverse engineered a PDF document by looking at the internal structure using PDFXplorer and used RichMedia annotation as you suggested. But the video is not showing up. I am kind of stuck at this point. I could not find any example of itext embedding video using RichMedia Annotation on the web either.